# Liquibase: Custom SQL statement

Tags: oracle, postgresql-9.1, liquibase

I have my liquibase schema defined initially for PostreSQL. Now, I have to modify the schema file to support Oracle. I have a change-set that has a `<sql>` tag. It has a query that accesses the `pg_catalog` table to set a value to the sequence. However, this will not work for Oracle. If I remove it, the Liquibase complains with check-sum validation fail. It complains even if I have an empty `<sql>` tag or some other query specified within. Within this change-set, I have many other create-table statement, so I cannot just remove oracle from dbms attribute. Is there any way I can suppress this sql from running for Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dbms attribute on the [changeset](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/changeset) is the mechanism designed to handle this problem..... Sounds like you're trying to do too much within one changesest (but I guess you've figured that out)

The checksum validation failure is liquibase's safety mechanism designed to defend the database against someone tampering with the schema files.

How to fix it is to use the [clearChecksums](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/command_line) option when running liquibase. It tells liquibase to recompute the checksums for the changesets already in the database. This will enable your postgres database instance to accept the alterations to its changesets that you've made for Oracle.

Comment: Yes, my schema file has one change-set for all create-table statements (around 69 tables), this is legacy code and already in production, so I cannot change refactor it. But clearChecksums would recompute for all change-sets, is that right? If so, I would rather avoid taking that risk.

Comment: @gotuskar Yes, it will recompute all changesets, but that's ok, provided you've only changed only one changeset. Changesets are the mechanism that liquibase uses to ensure that the changeset presented is the same one that was previously applied. It's also how liquibase can support the "runOnChange" attribute (only apply the changeset if it has been changed). I suggest testing it out on a a copy of your production database.

Comment: Since I am porting my application to Oracle, I have changed many change-sets, thats why I have hold myself back from using this option.

Comment: @gotuskar Fact is you have changed the changesets that make up your schema. Oh well, in that case sounds like you're forced to branch (or fork) your schema.

Comment: Yes, as of now, I have separated out the schema code. I am still thinking of the clearChecksums option. I have probably just one change-set that has checksum violation. For other change-sets, I have just added oracle to the dbms attribute, so they would not affect. But, still I am quite scared to go ahead with this option. I am quite new to LiquiBase, so I am not sure which other corner cases I would test.

Comment: Is there a way in LiquiBase to identify which checksums would be affected and which would not, sort of a consolidated output just listing the change-sets that would change. I know one way is the run without the clearChecksums option and identify the failures. It should only have those change-sets that I want to really change. However, I was looking for similar output with clearChecksums option.

Comment: Liquibase uses it's own table to record information about changesets. Run the following SQL statement to see the info stored "SELECT * FROM DATABASECHANGELOG". Have fun!

Comment: I am of that table, however, it won't serve my purpose. It won't provide me with details which change-sets would change. That table just stores the author, id, file, .. and MD5. I will have to generate MD5 for each of my change-sets and compare. Nah! Not a good option. I will follow with what I stated before. Thanks for all the inputs.